# Joda DateTime ISODateTimeFormat pattern

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

The Joda [ISODateTimeFormat](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateTime--) docs say `ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime()` returns a formatter for the pattern **yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ**

But the formatter returns a "Z" in place of +00:00
see this-

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC);

DateTimeFormatter patternFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ");
DateTimeFormatter isoFormat = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime();

System.out.println(dt.toString(patternFormat));     //2014-06-01T03:02:13.552+00:00
System.out.println(dt.toString(isoFormat));         //2014-06-01T03:02:13.552Z
```

Can anyone tell me what the pattern would be to get the +00:00 to print as a Z

**Edit:
Just to clarify- I know that the 'Z' is the same as +00:00 but textually it is different. What I am asking is what pattern would place a Z as the time offset instead of +00:00**

*(Sorry if this is too trivial. I wanted to use the ISO format without milliseconds and in the course of writing this question I found exactly what I was after in `ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis()` so I am asking now only for interests sake)*

Comment: This Question seems to be misunderstood. I believe the question is: *Why do Joda-Time date-time values with an offset of zero (+00:00) sometimes generate strings ending with a `Z` and sometimes ending with a `+00:00`? How do I specify one ending rather than the other?*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It doesn't appear that you can build such a formatter purely from a pattern. The DateTimeFormat doc says:

> **Zone**:
>
> - 'Z' outputs offset without a colon,
> - 'ZZ' outputs the offset with a colon,
> - 'ZZZ' or more outputs the zone id.

You can build most of the formatter from a pattern and then customise the time zone output like this:

```
    DateTimeFormatter patternFormat = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
        .appendTimeZoneOffset("Z", true, 2, 4)
        .toFormatter();
```

Comment: for those who didn't get it on the first read - customize the first param of appendTimeZoneOffset, e.g. instead of calling `.appendTimeZoneOffset("Z", true, 2, 4)` change it to  `.appendTimeZoneOffset("+00:00", true, 2, 4)`!

Answer (score 3):

```
But the formatter returns a "Z" in place of +00:00 see this-
```

See doc again, it said clearly,

```
The time zone offset is 'Z' for zero, and of the form '±HH:mm' for non-zero.
```

So this ISO value **2014-06-01T03:02:13.552Z** is equivalent to **2014-06-01T03:02:13.552+00:00**.

In your code to see non-zero case, try with

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.now(); //without arg DateTimeZone.UTC;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added a clarification to my question. I know that Z and +00:00 are the same thing, but I am asking what pattern would I use to display the Z instead of +00:00.
 
If I use DateTime.now() it creates a date with my default offset. Something quite different again.

Comment: @DavePile Your question about `DateTime.now()` having a default offset is an orthogonal issue, unrelated to your main Question of format of generated strings. Key idea: **The JVM’s current default time zone is assigned to new DateTime objects if you fail to specify a time zone.** If you want that "now" date-time value to be in UTC (or whatever), then say so. Like this: `DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.UTC )`. Or for local Québec time: `DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal") )`.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that your TimeZone will always be DateTimeZone.UTC, then you can inject the Z in the pattern just like the T character has been injected. Something like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter patternFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
```

If you want to have the same format but without the milliseconds, the pattern might look something like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter patternFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
```

I am sure you have found this page, but see the [Joda Time Formatting](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_format.html) reference page for details regarding these formats and other options.

Answer (score 0):

`'Z'` is the short term for `Zulu time`, which is the same as `GMT` or `UTC`

I think this is what you need ..!!

```
int offset = DateTimeZone.forID("UTC").getOffset(new DateTime());
```